# How Can I Read The XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'm getting geografic info from a webservice. 
I'm trying to parse the return data for hours, but have been getting no where.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(result, LoadOptions.None);
```

i got this

```
 document   <html>
  <body>
    <state>Apure</state>
    <municipality>RÓMULO GALLEGOS</municipality>
    <parish>URBANA ELORZA</parish>
    <street>La Trinidad De Arauca</street>
  </body>
</html> System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
```

I try

```
document.Elements("state")
document.Descendants("body")
document.GetElementsByTagName("state");
```

But nothing.

I'm sure there is a simple way of do something so basic.

I'm seriously considering convert that to a string and do the parsing myself.

**Aditional consideration:**

The fields include it in the result is variable. 
Because some info doesnt have all fields.

Comment: What's the actual problem?  That's not valid xml you've shown, so an exception would be thrown.  If it's just a question formatting problem, then what results do you get?  `But nothing` is not helpful.

Comment: I get to the 'document' part without error. I want read the content. If document.Descendats("body") give me a collection of elements I could cycle to get each content. But doesn't. Instead give a Linq Container. I want to know how i get something like Obj.state  or Obj[0].value

Comment: `document.Descendants("state").First().Value`

Comment: It works fine for me.  There must be more to it.

Comment: Yes, was my fault, i translate the field name to english, and forgot to translate back :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I make a change.

I read a XElement instead of a XDocument;

```
XElement sitemap = XElement.Parse(result, LoadOptions.None);
foreach (var bodyElement in sitemap.Elements("body"))
{
    foreach (var fieldElement in bodyElement.Elements())
    {
       Console.WriteLine(fieldElement.Name);
       Console.WriteLine(fieldElement.Value);
    }
}
```

Probably there is a way to skip the first foreach, but still looking for it.
@Jonesy line works but that mean I have to know the fields names. This way i just create the info for the values I got.